xslt transformation to deduplicate objects
I'm serializing java objects to XML, and later need to transform that xml via xslt.
In this particular transformation, I need to delete a node (=Java field) called fieldToDelete, which can contain a bunch of irrelevant information. However, it can also contain nodes called gemeinde:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <fieldToDelete>
        <gemeinde id="10">
            <child1/>
        </gemeinde>
    </fieldToDelete>
    <fieldToDelete>
        <gemeinde id="20">
            <child2/>
        </gemeinde>
    </fieldToDelete>
    <gemeinde reference="10"/>
    <gemeinde reference="20"/>
    <gemeinde reference="10"/>
    <gemeinde reference="20"/>
</root>

I delete these nodes with
<xsl:template match="fieldToDelete"/>

However, because this also deletes <gemeinde>, I need to restore the reference.
The result should look like this:
<root>
    <gemeinde id="10">
        <child1/>
    </gemeinde>
    <gemeinde id="20">
        <child2/>
    </gemeinde>
    <gemeinde reference="10"/>
    <gemeinde reference="20"/>
</root>

The fieldToDelete is gone, and the first <gemeinde reference="1234"> is replaced with the full object, which initially resided inside the fieldToDelete.
My approach:

Duplication: Replace all references to gemeinde with the original, full gemeinde-object.
Delete the unwanted field
De-duplicate: Replace all but the first occurence of <gemeinde> with a reference.

This is my xslt:
<!-- For all <gemeinde reference="<id>">, copy the referenced object instead -->
<xsl:template match="gemeinde[@reference]">
    <xsl:variable name="refId" select="@reference"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//gemeinde[@id = $refId]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Delete obsolete field (which contains <gemeinde> sub-element) -->
<xsl:template match="fieldToDelete"/>

<!-- We might now have duplicate <gemeinde> definitions, replace all but the first one with a reference instead -->
<xsl:template match="gemeinde[@id]">
    <xsl:variable name="refId" select="@id"/>

    <xsl:if test="preceding::gemeinde[@id=$refId]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Rename 'id' attribute to 'reference' -->
            <xsl:attribute name="reference">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

However, this code (in particular the "preceding" clause) doesn't seem to work correctly.
The full <gemeinde> nodes are not replaced with references.
Caveats:

The id/reference is important. There can be multiple gemeinde objects with different IDs, and they must not be mixed up.
It's possible that the <fieldToDelete> does not contain a <gemeinde id="1234">, but a <gemeinde reference="1234">. This can happen if a <gemeinde> node already appeared before the fieldToDelete in the XML. (The first occurence of gemeinde always has an id, all other nodes only have a reference.)


Can you show us (in an edit to your question) the result XML you want to achieve with XSLT for your shown XML input sample?

@MartinHonnen sure. I added the expected result.

Your input XML is missing end tags for the gemeinde elements!

Your approach can only work if you chained two transformation (steps), i.e. either run two different, chained stylesheet or if you use two modes.
I would suggest to use keys
  <xsl:key name="gemeinde-by-id" match="gemeinde" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="gemeinde-by-ref" match="gemeinde" use="@reference"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="fieldToDelete"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="gemeinde[@reference][. is key('gemeinde-by-ref', @reference)[1]]">
    <xsl:sequence select="key('gemeinde-by-id', @reference)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

That is XSLT 3 code, if you use an XSLT 1 processor you would need to use xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:sequence and rewrite . is key('gemeinde-by-ref', @reference)[1] as generate-id() = generate-id(key('gemeinde-by-ref', @reference)[1]).
Furthermore the xsl:mode would need to be spelled out as a template
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Using the XSLT 3 approach at the online fiddle I get the result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    
    
    <gemeinde id="10">
            <child1/>
        </gemeinde>
    <gemeinde id="20">
            <child2/>
        </gemeinde>
    <gemeinde reference="10"/>
    <gemeinde reference="20"/>
</root>


Sorry, I just found out that my question wasn't completely clear. Your answer works for the first ID, but if I delete multiple elements (containing many  objects with different IDs), the following IDs are not deleted.

@maja, I have used the input from your latest edit to your question with my suggested code and I think it produces the desired output. Perhaps, if there are still issues with more complex inputs, you can raise a new question where you state which XSLT processor/version you use, show sample of XML input, desired output, tried XSLT and wrong output you get.

Your question is not very clear. Maybe something like this could work for you:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="gi" match="gemeinde" use="@reference" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="fieldToDelete/gemeinde"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="gemeinde[generate-id() = generate-id(key('gi', @reference)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

This copies the gemeinde elements inside fieldToDelete and then uses the Muenchian method to de-dupe the gemeinde elements that are children of root.
